# Why does .htaccess RewriteRule not work in root path / but with for all other files and subdirs?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the [Nextcloud Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud) and replaced the original .htaccess file with the following code to test redirecting all requests:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule . /foo\.php [L,R=307]
</IfModule>
```

Every access is redirected, except the root, which I opened as follows:

http://192.168.178.9:8666/?randomchars (randomchar to avoid redirect caching)

[image]

The .htaccess is in the root dir:

[image]

The following URL is redirected as well:

http://192.168.178.9:8666/index.php?randomchars

So this is only valid for the "/" path. What could be the reason?

Comment: `/` or the directory the htaccess is located in is treated as an empty URI. You need to use `^$` to match against the root directory. In your case this should work if you use `.*` instead of `.` in the pattern.

Comment: Or use `^` instead of `.` to match everything (including empty)

Comment: Will test and return feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you redirect rule has 2 issues:

1. It doesn't redirect landing page (as you have found out)
2. Is going to cause a redirect loop since `/foo.php` will also be redirected to `/foo.php` and there is no condition to stop that redirect.

You may use this redirect rule that handles both issues:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^foo\.php$ /foo.php [NC,L,R=307]
```

`!^foo\.php$` is negated condition to avoid redirect if URI is already `/foo.php`.

Comment: The negation did not work in my final code but `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo\.php$ RewriteRule .* /foo\.php [L,R=307]` worked.